# Using $\epsilon$ - $N$ method to find convergence of sequence of simple rational expressions of polynomials - technique question

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Working through *Spivak's Calculus, Ch.22* in an example he discusses the convergence of the following sequence:

$$\frac{3n^{3} + 7n^{2} + 1}{4n^{3} - 8n + 64}$$

He treats it in the usual way of handling these sorts of expressions, specifically:

$$\frac{3 + \frac{7}{n} + \frac{1}{n^{3}}}{4 - \frac{8}{n^{2}} + \frac{64}{n^{3}}}$$

eventually taking the $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}} = \frac{3}{4}$.

I was doing it as an exercise for myself how to determine this convergence using the definition of a convergent sequence:

> A sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ converges to a $l$ if for every $\epsilon >0$ there is a natural number $N$ such that for all natural numbers $n$, if $n > N$, then $|a_{n} - l| < \epsilon$.

So using the same ideas presented and a technique from the book, the rough work I'm going through right now is the following:

$$\bigg|n^{3} \bigg(\frac{3 + \frac{7}{n} + \frac{1}{n^{3}}}{4 - \frac{8}{n^{2}} + \frac{64}{n^{3}}} \bigg) - \frac{3}{4} \bigg|$$

The next step I took was working with in particular the fractional terms and I wanted to bound them. Given that $|n| \geq 1$, individually the following are true:

$$\bigg|\frac{7}{n} + \frac{1}{n^{3}}\bigg| \leq \bigg|\frac{7}{n}\bigg| + \bigg|\frac{1}{n^{3}}\bigg| \leq |7| + |7| = 14 \\ \text{also} \\ \bigg|\frac{8}{n^{2}} + \frac{64}{n^{3}}\bigg| \leq \bigg|\frac{8}{n^{2}}\bigg| + \bigg|\frac{64}{n^{3}}\bigg| \leq |8| + |63| = 71$$

So using these relationships I can conclude from them:

$$ -14 \leq \frac{7}{n} + \frac{1}{n^{3}} < 14 \\ -71 = -(|8| + |63|) \leq \frac{8}{n^{2}} + \frac{64}{n^{3}} < |8| + |63| = 71\\  \text{(there's a reason I kept $|8| + |63|$ in the expression here that I will explain.}\\ \text{Also not sure if I needed to treat the absolute values around $14$ or $71$ in any particular way)}$$

So for the most part I have some bounds, but my issue is how to properly reason out the subtraction in the denominator of my main expression ? i.e saying:

$$\bigg|n^{3} \bigg(\frac{3 + \frac{7}{n} + \frac{1}{n^{3}}}{4 - \frac{8}{n^{2}} + \frac{64}{n^{3}}} \bigg) - \frac{3}{4} \bigg| \leq \bigg|n^{3}\bigg(\frac{3 + 7 + 7}{4 - 8 + 63}\bigg) - \frac{3}{4}\bigg|$$

I guess looking at it now, if I instead treated $\frac{8}{n^{2}}$ and $\frac{64}{n^{3}}$ individually, I could have said "given $n \geq 1$, then observe $\frac{8}{n^{2}} < 8$" and as such my denominator would follow.

After this it is just an algebraic manipulation to find the specific $N$ from the expression

$$\bigg|\frac{17N^{3}}{59} - \frac{3}{4}\bigg| < \epsilon$$

And as every math author does, this can be left as an exercise.

TL:DR: Did I treat the denominator of my expression correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an issue in the inequality right after "So for the most part...".  The issue here is that $a<b$ doesn't imply $|a|<|b|$.  Ex: let $a=-4$ and let $b=2$.  Then $a<b$, but $|a|>|b|$.  Also, it looks like you got your inequality reversed on that step.  Since you have $a<b$, then $\frac{1}{a}>\frac{1}{b}$, and it looks like you have $a<b$ implies $\frac{1}{a}<\frac{1}{b}$.

I recommend creating one fraction, meaning consider

$$\left|\frac{3n^3+7n^2+1}{4n^3−8n+64}-\frac{3}{4} \right| = \left| \frac{4(3n^3+7n^2+1)-3(4n^3-8n+64)}{4(4n^3-8n+64)} \right| \\
= \frac{\left|4(3n^3+7n^2+1)-3(4n^3-8n+64)\right|}{\left| 4(4n^3-8n+64) \right|}
\\=\frac{\left|28n^2+24n-188 \right|}{\left| 4(4n^3-8n+64) \right|} \\
=\frac{\left|7n^2+6n-47 \right|}{\left| 4n^3-8n+64 \right|} \\
\leq \frac{7n^2}{\left| 4n^3-8n+64 \right|}+\frac{6n}{\left| 4n^3-8n+64 \right|}+\frac{47}{\left|4n^3-8n+64 \right|}.$$

Use the divergent nature of $4n^3-8n+64$ to help you find a large enough $N$ such that $n\geq N$ inmplies that that each term is less than $\varepsilon/3$.

Comment: What do you specifically mean by the divergent nature ? I do see that $4n^{3} - 8n + 64$ in itself will diverge to $\infty$, but after that I'm not sure. Specifically I am gathering you mean something along the lines of $\frac{7n^{2}}{|n^{3}||4 - \frac{8}{n^{2}} + \frac{64}{n^{3}}|} < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$ (just using this one as an example), then concluding something form this.

Comment: That's the right idea.  After simplifying you get $4n-\frac{8}{n}+\frac{64}{n^2}$, which goes to $\infty$ as $n$ gets large.  So choose $N_1$ large enough such that $n \geq N_1$ implies that $|4n-\frac{8}{n}+\frac{64}{n^2}|>\frac{21}{\varepsilon}$.  This forces the first term to be $< \frac{\varepsilon}{3}$.  Choose a similar $N_2$ and $N_3$, and let $n \geq \max \{N_1, N_2, N_3\}$.